# How to make data ownership explicit in C++

Tags: c++

When working with pointers and references in C++, it is sometimes difficult to see whether the pointer has ownership over the referenced data, or if it is just a temporal reference. For example:

```
Instance* i = new Instance();
Instance* j = i;
```

**How can it be made clear which of the 2 pointers has ownership over the instance?** In other words, how to make clear on which pointer delete has to be called?

*Note:* In the above example this is not hard to see, as it is a very short piece of code. However, when the pointer is duplicated and passed around a lot, this can become unclear.

Comment: your question doesn't make sense. neither reference has 'ownership'. They are both, equally valid references

Comment: That's exactly my problem, and I wonder how it is best to document which pointer has the responsibility to delete the instance. I'dd like a language feature for this, although I have not a clue how this could be done.

Comment: +1 Why are you downvoting this question?

Comment: @Magnus Skog: I was wondering the same thing. The original used references instead of pointers in the example, and I think that confused people. I still think the aggressive downvotes were uncalled for, but what can you do?

Comment: You should consider that the responsibility to delete an object is assigned to a variable but to the object that instantiated it.

Comment: Dimitri posted an answer to his own question (since deleted), which is that shared_ptr is the solution - so according to his own interpretation of his question, it's a duplicate of dozens of other SO questions. So perhaps that attracted the downvotes (though not from me, as it happens).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot determine the owner, since there is no built in mechanism to know which pointer is owning the memory the pointer points to.

If you are really concerned about this, you could always introduce your own naming convention, e.g. through some pre/post-fix to your variable names. In other words, it's your code design that can give you this information. Since you (and your coworkers) are writing the code you can always make sure that this design is enforced during implementation. This of course means that everyone has to follow these "rules".

This is one reason why a common coding convention is so important. So you can read your own and other peoples code and understand it.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, it seems unnecessarily confounding to use a reference to refer to data that must be deleted. Use a pointer instead.

Secondly, if you want to indicate ownership of an object, use a wrapper class that manages ownership. There is `auto_ptr` specifically for this purpose, although it has shortcomings. (These should be addressed by unique_ptr in the next version of the language, though that doesn't help you now).

Thirdly, in the simplest cases (as often as possible), don't use the heap directly. Just declare a local object, e.g.

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

This doesn't stop you transfering ownership when you need to (use `swap`).

Comment: This is just an example. When using polymorphism, it is necessary.

Comment: I use polymorphism all the time in C++. I've never found it necessary.

Comment: It is not necessary to use a reference for polymorphism. A pointer works just fine. If you have a reference to an object, it's like saying "Whatever you do, don't delete this!" With a pointer, it is more open to being deleted (although still requires an understanding of the design/ownership).

Comment: A reference is just a pointer that is guaranteed not to be null.

Comment: @Dimitri C: A reference is more than that (or less, depending on how you look at it). A reference cannot be reassigned.

Comment: @e.James: Indeed, that's another a big difference. It's an advantageous limitation adding to the usefulness of references.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like `shared_ptr<>` to explicitly share ownership.  If you want to maintain a clear single owner with other non-owner pointers referring to the same object, you could use something like `boost::scoped_ptr<>` for the owning pointer and have a typedef for non-owning pointers:

```
typedef Instance* UnownedInstance_ptr;   // or some better name
```

This would at least document intent. I don't know of a way off the top of my head to have a smart pointer type that prevents the ability to delete the contained pointer and prevent copying the pointer into another smart pointer that takes ownership (since the source doesn't have any ownership to give away), but that might be an interesting class to represent that policy.

Answer (score 3):

For me I would go with the Hungarian Notation!

Joel tells you the rest ::
[Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)

an example in your case ::

```
Instance* Owener_i = new Instance();
Instance* Observer_j = i;
.
.
.
.
.
delete Observer_j; // Wrong! not an Owner.
```

Answer (score 2):

As the others indicated - use a convention. I use raw pointers for non-owning variables, and the owner is usually wrapped into some kind of smart pointer (such as boost::scoped_ptr) or even not a pointer at all but an object created on the stack.